# How to select by custom post type AND order by custom post field + title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We have a custom post type called 'projekt' and are using the following query succesfully:

```
$args_wb = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekt',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'meta_key' => 'jahr',   
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array('key' => 'projekt_typ', 'value' => 'Wohnbau')
        );
```

How do we extend this to order by jahr descending AND by post title ascending?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem ourselves. Was easier than we thought!

```
$args_wb = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekt',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'meta_key' => 'jahr',   
        'orderby' => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC'),
        'meta_query' => array('key' => 'projekt_typ', 'value' => 'Wohnbau')
        );
```